# How to subtract the current date from a date in a cell (VBA)?

Tags: vba, excel

Hi just a quick question,
I currently have a simple VBA macro set up where it searches from cell B3:B10000 to search for cells with the exact color 49407 and if it does then it will display it in a message box. This part of the program works fine however when i try to add a second loop where it searches from cell D3:D10000 for a date that is 15 days before today's date it does not work and it shows every result in the sheet. i tried using both DateAdd and taking 15 away from the currentDate which i had set to = "Now()".

Basically my question is as follows am i doing this wrong and if so how do i correct it?
Also is it possible to put all messages into one message box instead of multiple boxes popping up one after the other?

The current code i have is as follows:

```
Sub dateSub()

Dim jobStatus As Boolean
jobStatus = False
Dim currentDate As Date
currentDate = Now()
Dim subDate As Date
subDate = DateAdd("d", -15, currentDate)
Dim jobID As String
Dim dateID As String

For Each ambercell In Range("B3:B10000")
    For Each dateCell In Range("D3:D10000")

    If ambercell.Cells.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 49407 & dateCell.Value < (currentDate - 15) Then
    jobID = ambercell.Text
    dateID = dateCell.Text
    MsgBox ("List of Job ID's that are still amber & are 15 days Overdue: " & jobID & " on " & dateID)
    End If

    Next
Next

End Sub
```

I was going to set up this simple macro and then expand on it in the future to maybe move all Amber cells over into a new sheet or look into more things i could do with VBA macros

Any help with this program will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

AlmightyThud

Comment: Replace your `&` with `AND`. Ampersands concatenates stuff, not what you want.

Comment: I also don't understand why you're looping. Do you just want the date match on rows with the color? If so, just check whether column D of the row with the color meets your date test.

Comment: Hi, ill give the AND a try and im checking if the date in the cell is < 15 days from the current date so i just assumed you would have to loop through the column. I'll give it a shot just checking through the cells rather than looping.

Comment: @OP : use the `if` inside first `for` loop. By the way, how come the Almighty(!) missed this?

Comment: @ZAT The Whole 'If'? or split it into two 'If' statements? and I guess i am not as almighty as i thought. Gonna change my name to "DecentThud"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub dateSub()

Dim jobStatus As Boolean
jobStatus = False
Dim currentDate As Date
currentDate = Now()
Dim subDate As Date
subDate = DateAdd("d", -15, currentDate)
Dim jobID As String
Dim dateID As String

For Each ambercell In Range("B3:B10000")
If ambercell.Cells.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 49407 Then
    'For Each dateCell In Range("D3:D10000")
     If ambercell.offset( ,2).Value < (currentDate - 15) Then
     jobID = ambercell.Value
     dateID = ambercell.offset( ,2).Value      'dateCell.offset( ,2).Value
     MsgBox ("List of Job ID's that are still amber & are 15 days Overdue: " & jobID & " on " & dateID)
     Else
     jobID = ambercell.Value
     dateID = ambercell.offset( ,2).Value      'dateCell.offset( ,2).Value
     MsgBox ("List of Job ID's that are still amber : " & jobID & " on " & dateID)
     End If
    'Next
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Forget my previous comment, i just replaced `dateCell.Offset(, 2).Value` and removed the second loop and it worked like a charm.

Comment: whats your requirement? if ambercell and datecell then show msgbox. right? Or, msgbox all ambercell and after that msgbox datecell.

Comment: my goal was to display both the jobID for all jobs in Amber and if that job was outstanding by 15 days. Got it working now so thanks a ton. Also Do you know if it is possible to put all that info into one message box or something similar?

Comment: still not clear! If amber msgbox both ID. within that msgbox show if date ID is differed by 15 days. Right?

Comment: Yea, thats pretty much it. It's a pretty simple program but i just wanted to be able to check through my whole spreadsheet.
It's all working now though thanks to you :)

Comment: see updated answer if needed. Adjust this if needed. Glad to help and Welcome for DecentThud.